# "filter is not a function" TypeError on computed property, simple filter with arrow function

Tags: vuejs2

In the below code snippet, if i remove `.filter(beer => beer.isFavourite)` the computed property works with no error, essentially becoming the same value as allBrewDogBeers.  When i add filter, i get `"TypeError: this.allBrewDogBeers.filter is not a function"`.  I think maybe this is to do with the context, but i don't really understand what i'm missing, because i've written a filter as simple as this before, but maybe Vue is confusing me.

I just want to have a computed property which is a subset of allBrewDogBeers, I v-bind this computed property to a favourite component in my template.

```
computed: {
    favouriteBeers: function() {
      return this.allBrewDogBeers.filter(beer => beer.isFavourite);
    }
  },
```

full script:

```
<script>
import { eventBus }  from './main.js'

import BeerList from './components/BeerList.vue'
import BeerDetail from './components/BeerDetail.vue'
import FavouriteBeers from './components/FavouriteBeers.vue'

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    'beer-list': BeerList,
    'beer-detail': BeerDetail,
    'favourite-beers': FavouriteBeers
  },
  data() {
    return {
      allBrewDogBeers: [],
      selectedBeer: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    favouriteBeers: function() {
      return this.allBrewDogBeers.filter(beer => beer.isFavourite);
    }
  },
  methods:{
      addFavourBeer: function(beer) {
        const index = this.allBrewDogBeers.indexOf(beer);
      this.allBrewDogBeers[index].isFavourite = true; 

      },
      removeFavourBeer: function(beer) {
        const index = this.allBrewDogBeers.indexOf(beer);
      this.allBrewDogBeers[index].isFavourite = false;
      }
    },
  mounted(){ 
      fetch("https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers")
      .then(response => this.allBrewDogBeers = response.json())
      .then(data => this.allBrewDogBeers = data);

      eventBus.$on('beer-selected', (beer) => {this.selectedBeer = beer});
      eventBus.$on('beer-favourite-add', beer => this.addFavourBeer(beer));
      eventBus.$on('beer-favourite-remove', beer => this.removeFavourBeer(beer));
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a problem here:

```js
.then(response => this.allBrewDogBeers = response.json())
```

That's assigning a promise to `this.allBrewDogBeers`, which isn't what you want.

Change it to:

```js
.then(response => response.json())
```

The other `then` will handle the assignment.

Comment: thank you so much, i'd missed this typo, and hadnt considered how it can cause this error, but that now makes sense!